# How Do I Update UIWebView After viewDidLoad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

This is my first iOS app, so I am probably missing something very simple.  Please be kind.  I have been tearing my hair out and I could really use some help.

#### Overview Of App

Basically, this is a single page application that just loads a UIWebView.  I have an external accessory (bluetooth barcode scanner) that I connect and basically what I want to do is when the the app receives a scan, I want to call a method in my ViewController and update the UIWebView accordingly.

#### What Is Working

I am able to connect the scanner, load the first view, which loads the initial webpage, scan a barcode and call the method in my controller.

#### My Problem

I can't seem to figure out how to update the UIWebView from the method in my controller.  It logs the url string to my debugger area, but never actually updates the webview.  I am pretty sure I have some delegation wrong or something with my webview instance.  There must be some glue code here that I am missing.

#### My Code HelloWorldViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KScan.h"

@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> { 

  IBOutlet UIWebView *page;
  IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

  Boolean IsFirstTime;

  KScan *kscan;

}

- (void)setFirstTime;
- (void)DisplayConnectionStatus; 
- (void)DisplayMessage:(char *)Message; 
- (void)newBarcodeScanned:(NSString *)barcode;
- (void)loadBarcodePage:(NSString *)barcode;

@property (nonatomic, retain) KScan *kscan;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *page;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myLabel;

@end
```

#### My Code HelloWorldViewController.m

```
#import "HelloWorldViewController.h"
#import "common.h"

@implementation HelloWorldViewController

@synthesize myLabel;
@synthesize page;
@synthesize kscan;


- (void)setFirstTime
{
    IsFirstTime = true;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.kscan = [[KScan alloc] init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    page.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    //page.delegate = self;

   [page loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.187:3000"]]];

}


- (void) newBarcodeScanned:(NSString *)barcode
{
NSLog(@"%s[%@]",__FUNCTION__, barcode);

[self loadBarcodePage:barcode];
} 

- (void)loadBarcodePage:(NSString *)barcode
{
NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/%@", barcode];
NSLog(@"%@", url);
[page loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]]; 

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [myLabel release];
    myLabel = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
       return YES;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
   [page release];
   [kscan release];
   [myLabel release];
   [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Basically, I am just trying to load google.com into my page webview when scanning a barcode.  My log statements are being logged with the correct URL, but this line of code doesn't work.

```
[page loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

I am not getting any errors and my xCode debugging skills are not the greatest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@", page);` say if you put it inside `loadBarcodePage`?  Also, try implementing the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods and see if there are any errors or notification of completion.

Comment: Well, NSLog(@"%@", page) returns (null) in the debugger area.

Comment: Can you specify what implementing UIWebViewDelegate methods are and how to implement them?  This is my first week with Objective-C.  I am just a stupid rails developer.

Comment: If you look at the protocol definition for UIWebViewDelegate, you'll see some methods that allow you to be notified when the request starts, completes, encounters an error...things like that.  However, if your web view is nil, that's a way of analyzing a **different** problem.

Comment: Here's something that may or may not work, but will clean up the code at least.  Remove `IBOutlet UIWebView *page;` and change the property declaration to `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *page;` and then make sure the storyboard connection for 'page' is set right.  Finally, change references to 'page' in your .m file to `self.page` (except synthesize).  The logic for this is to make sure you're always referencing the property.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll give it a shot and see where it goes.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your webview is never allocated, or added to your main view. You are probably talking to a nil instance.

Unless your web view comes from a XIB file (which I doubt since it is not declared as an IBOutlet in your heder file) try adding something like this to your viewDidLoad:

```
self.page = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.page];
```

Comment: I can confirm that by logging page it is null and I am talking to air, but this doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I am using a storyboard if that makes any difference.  Why does it load the page the first time then?